# MongoDB driver for .NET - id property setter never called

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a post class which may contain a product class as a property.
The product's “id” property never gets set, while “stock_quantity” does.

Any ideas why that may be? The document in the DB is valid and the id of the product is set to an integer value of the number type.
I just updated the mongo driver nuget to the latest c# version (as of 2021-08-24)

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class Post {
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string _Id { get; set; }
    
    [BsonElement("ID")]
    public int Id {get;set;}

    [BsonElement("post_name")]
    public string Slug {get;set;}

    [BsonElement("product")]
    public Product.Product Product {get;set;}
}

[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class Product {        
    [BsonElement("id")]
    public int id {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [BsonElement("stock_quantity")]
    public int StockQuantity {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```